# Why does linker fail when accessing static member in inline constructor

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static, linker

Just started doing some coding for a very simple automated test framework for internal use. (I know there are hundreds of them out there - really good ones too, but at the moment that's not interesting, so don't point me to any of those, please ;)) I then came across the following problem which I can't explain, thus asking for your help.

I have the following code as part of a DLL:

(The code is barely an embryo and took me <2 minutes to write, so it's logic, structure - nothing - is refined, in any way yet.)

h-file:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __DLL__   // Defined in DLL-project
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec( dllexport )
#else
    #define DLLEXPORT
#endif

class DLLEXPORT AutoTest
{
public:
            enum    eTestID {TESTID_SomeFunction};
                    AutoTest(eTestID id, LPVOID lpData)
                    {
                        if(sm_bTestsActive)
                            ExecTest(id, lpData);
                    }
            void    ActivateTests();

private:
    static  void    ExecTest(eTestID id, LPVOID lpData)
                    {
                    }
    static  BOOL    sm_bTestsActive;
};
```

cpp-file:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "AutoTest.hpp"

BOOL AutoTest::sm_bTestsActive = FALSE;

void AutoTest::ActivateTests()
{
    sm_bTestsActive=TRUE;
}
```

**This compiles just fine and the DLL gets generated.**

Here's my problem though - when instantiating the class with:

```
AutoTest(AutoTest::TESTID_SomeFunction, &SomeData);
```

from the main application, the linker fails with

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int AutoTest::sm_bTestsActive" (?sm_bTestsActive@AutoTest@@0HA)
```

*<2 minutes to write - now going on 5 hours to understand why it fails!!! :O*

Here's what interesting - if I move the constructor to the cpp-file (not inlined) it works just fine!?!?

Here's that code:

h-file:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __DLL__   // Defined in DLL-project
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec( dllexport )
#else
    #define DLLEXPORT
#endif

class DLLEXPORT AutoTest
{
public:
            enum    eTestID {FK3059};
                    AutoTest(eTestID id, LPVOID lpData);
            void    ActivateTests();

private:
    static  void    ExecTest(eTestID id, LPVOID lpData)
                    {
                    }
    static  BOOL    sm_bTestsActive;
};
```

cpp-file:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "AutoTest.hpp"

BOOL AutoTest::sm_bTestsActive = FALSE;

AutoTest::AutoTest(eTestID id, LPVOID lpData)
{
    if(sm_bTestsActive)
        ExecTest(id, lpData);
}

void AutoTest::ActivateTests()
{
    sm_bTestsActive=TRUE;
}
```

(I've made some minor edits in the code after pasting, so there may or may not be simple syntax errors.)

Also, if I remove the reference to the static member from the inline versions constructor, it works fine.

Any ideas as to why the inline version won't work?

Comment: My guess is you are calling the constructor from another library and are not linking with the DLL.

Comment: @DDrmmr The files/class is part of our "Backbone" DLL that's used **a lot** from the "client". And it wouldn't work with the non-inline version either.

Comment: How is `DLLEXPORT` defined?

Comment: Shouldn't the user of that DLL have a class declaration marked DLL import? You don't export the class from your application. At any rate, this is definitely highly compiler/OS-specific.

Comment: @hvd That's usually done with a clever definition of the `DLLEXPORT` macro and linker flags, however unclear how it's being done here.

Comment: @BartoszKP In that case I would strongly suggest renaming that macro. The name `DLLEXPORT` should never mean "maybe export, maybe import, we'll see". :)

Comment: You should seriously rework your C++ style. I found it largely confusing and it's not one of the common ones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style -- edit: tbh, it confuses me just enough to not care about a solution :S

Comment: @hvd Yeah, I know what you mean, however from what I've encountered it's quite common to call it like that. In the meaning: "this is an exported class/function" (whether it will be marked as export/import depends on the context, but conceptually it's "exported from somewhere").

Comment: @hvd Sorry for not including that info - it's `#define DLLEXPORT __declspec( dllexport )` - I see what you're getting at... I'll do some testing. Got so confused that i worked as non-inline that I missed that.

Comment: @phresnel LOL You may be right. But I'm kind of stuck in ways I've been doing it for the last 31 years working as a coder ;)

Comment: @hvd Edited the code to include DLLEXPORT-macro definition.

Comment: @ClasG: Ah, now I understand, ..., maybe: That's punchtape style, with fixed columns for things like `enum` and so on, right? ;)

Comment: @phresnel Spot on! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
#ifdef __DLL__   // Defined in DLL-project
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec( dllexport )
#else
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
```

> You can declare C++ classes with the `dllimport` or `dllexport` attribute. These forms imply that the entire class is imported or exported. Classes exported this way are called exportable classes.

More information in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to your definition of `DLLEXPORT`.

Make sure that it is properly expanded to `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the DLL, or `__declspec(dllimport)` when building the client.

I'd suggest using a macro with a more specific name than the generic `DLLEXPORT` (to avoid conflicts with other macros with the same name).

Having static data members accessed from inline member functions works fine for me (tested with VS2013).

Minimal repro:

Create a Visual Studio solution with an empty DLL project and an empty console application project.

Inside the DLL project add two files:

**DllClass.h**:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TEST_DLL_CLASS
#define TEST_DLL_CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class TEST_DLL_CLASS DllClass
{
public:
    DllClass();

    int GetMember() const
    {
        return m_data1;
    }

    static int GetStaticMember()
    {
        return sm_data2;
    }

private:
    int m_data1;
    static int sm_data2;
};
```

**DllClass.cpp**:

```
#define TEST_DLL_CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#include "DllClass.h"

int DllClass::sm_data2 = 2;

DllClass::DllClass()
    : m_data1(1)
{
}
```

Inside the console app project, add one file:

**Test.cpp**:

```
#include "..\DllTestClass\DllClass.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "DllTestClass")

int main()
{
    DllClass dllClass;

    cout << dllClass.GetMember() << endl;
    cout << DllClass::GetStaticMember() << endl;
}
```

Make sure that when building the console test app, the linker can find the DLL .lib (*DllTestClass.lib*) file.
For that purpose, you can navigate the console app's project properties, going to:

```
Project Properties | Linker | Additional Library Directories
```

and add `$(OutDir)` to the additional library directories, making it:

```
$(OutDir);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

Builds and works correctly for me.

Comment: BartoszKP beat you to it but up-voted for effort **and** the fact that you got me thinking of the name... Decided on `DLL_VISIBILITY` in lack of a better word. Any other suggestions? ([Discussion here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167620/what-is-a-single-word-that-means-both-import-and-export))

Comment: @ClasG: I don't know what you mean with _"beat you to it"_. To be honest, @BartoszKP's _initial_ answer was wrong: I had a comment pointing that out, and he honestly agreed on that, and removed his original answer. (Then, I removed my comment since the wrong initial answer was removed.) Anyway, for the naming, I'd suggest some name specific to your DLL, and crafted to make it difficult to collide with other names, something like `YOUR_COMPANY_NAME_YOUR_DLL_PROJECT_NAME_DLL_EXPORT` (e.g. `FOO_AUTO_TEST_DLL_EXPORT`).

Comment: Sorry for not keeping the entire comment history in my head :P The name should however be something more (semi-) generic for our solution. Thanks.

Comment: No problem :) Feel free to choose the name you prefer, of course.